# Objective-C EXC_BAD_ACCESS on run

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a basic command line application using this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/40293/learn-to-code-ios-apps-2-strings-arrays-objects-and-classes

I'm at the stage where it is asks me to type in:

```
NSLog(@"You entered the word '%@' and it is %li characters long", inputString, [inputString length]);
```

When I do that, run the app and type in a word in the console window it says I should get

```
Please enter a word.
objects
You entered the word 'objects' and it is 7 characters long
```

Which does happen, but then the screen automatically switches to:

[image: xcode error]

the error on the green bar says:

```
 Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: You'll have to post more code.

Answer (score 3):

Run the Zombies instrument in Instruments. The crash is caused by releasing an invalid "object". Probably this is because the object was over-released. The Zombies instrument will tell you more about over-release problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that line of code.

What's likely happening is that you have nothing *after* that line of code, and those lines  you typed in need to live ***between*** the brackets in this template:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
         // your code goes HERE
    }
    return 0;
}
```